# the callback function doesn't see 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

my callback function doesn't see 'this'

here is my code of binding keypress:

```
     initialize: function () {
        $(document).bind('keyup', this.keyPress);
        _.bindAll(this, 'rotate');
     },
     rotate: function (event) {
        //smth...
     }
```

here is function keyPress:

```
     keyPress: function(event) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
        var pageX = 0, pageY = 0;
        var ev = new Object();
        ev.pageY = pageY;
        ev.pageX = pageX;

        func = this.rotate;
        func(ev);
        //also I tried like this:
        //this.rotate(ev);
    }
```

it is an error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

I can't get it.

I will really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Ideally you need to show more code, so we get a better idea of where things are scoped and what `this` is intending to actually be

Comment: What is `this` referencing, and where is the `keyPress` hander defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in JQuery, bind adds an event listener, it does not set the context of 'this'

You need to bind the method to the context, using underscore.

e.g.

```
 initialize: function () {
    $(document).bind('keyup', _.bind(this.keyPress, this));
    _.bindAll(this, 'rotate');
 },
 rotate: function (event) {
    //smth...
 }
```

That will ensure that 'this' refers to the correct object

Comment: You could also bind the context at the function itself - keyPress: function(e) { ... }.bind(this)

Comment: @LouisK: But `this` wouldn't be the instance when `keyPress` was being defined, `this` would probably be `window` at that time. `$(document).bind('keyup', this.keyPress.bind(this))` would work though or `_.bindAll(this, 'rotate', 'keyPress'); $(document).bind('keyup', this.keyPress)`.

Comment: This still leaves a stray binding to `document` if this view is removed or if another is created. There should be a `remove` override to [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) this binding and that would work better with the `_.bindAll` approach (or an event namespace). Of course, whatever was managing the views would need to call `remove` before replacing the view.